# Which arguments of `\includegraphics` cannot be set beforehand?

Tags: graphics, pgfkeys

From the documentation of the `graphicx` package:

> Most of the `keyval` keys used in the `graphicx` package may also be set using the command `\setkeys` provided by the `keyval` package.
>
> For instance, suppose you wanted all the files to be included in the
>   current document to be scaled to 75% of the width of the lines of
>   text, then one could issue the following command:
>
> ```
> \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.75\textwidth}
> ```
>
> Here `‘Gin’` is the name used for
>   the `keyval` keys associated with ‘Graphics inclusion’. All following
>   `\includegraphics` commands (within the same group or environment) will
>   act as if `[width=0.75\textwidth]` had been specified, in addition to
>   any other key settings actually given in the optional argument.

I am trying to use this to create an argument that accepts keys using the `pgfkeys` package and passes the ones it does not recognize on to an `\includegraphics` command. Here's a toy working example:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\mykeyset}[1]{\pgfqkeys{/me}{#1}}

\mykeyset{graphic options/.code={}}
\mykeyset{set graphic option/.style={graphic options/.append code=#1}}

%Set up a handler for unknown keys
\mykeyset{.unknown/.code = %
    {%
        \edef\unknownkey{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
        \mykeyset{set graphic option/.expand once = {\expandafter\setkeys\expandafter{\expandafter G\expandafter i\expandafter n\expandafter}\expandafter{\unknownkey=#1}}}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{\begingroup%
    \mykeyset{#1}%
    \mykeyset{graphic options}%
    \includegraphics{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\myincludegraphics[width = 5cm, height = 8cm]{example-image}
\myincludegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\myincludegraphics{example-image}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

Note that this works for the `width` and `height` keys, but that not for the `scale` key.  This is not a problem in itself--I have a method for handling the `scale` key separately--but I would like to know which other keys require special treatment. Hence, my question:

**Which keys to the `\includegraphics` command cannot be set globally?**

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31012/484

Comment: `scale` seems to be set and required on-the-fly. Same goes for `angle`...

Comment: @Werner well spotted, I think that's the full list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brilliant documentation isn't it:-)

In general setting keys is more or less just making macro definitions, so the ones you can't set in advance are the ones that are initialised by `\includegraphics` before it processes the keys. Looking at the code (strangely more revealing than the documentation) the only relevant initialisation is

```
   \@tempswafalse
```

and the keys that use that boolean flag are just `angle` and `scale`.

The reason for the flag is that most graphics inclusion back ends can "natively" scale the image so if scale is used on its own it is passed on to the back end driver code, but if the image has already been rotated and then the rotated image is scaled, `\includegraphics` essentially inserts a  `\scalebox{}{\rotatebox{...` around the basic image inclusion.  Perhaps it could have been handled differently so your scale example works, but it was a long time ago:-)

For slightly different reasons `clip` should also be listed, see

http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=graphics/2890