# How to change one thing to change all

Tags: graphics, scaling

I have the following but when I change scale, I have to change all images. Is there a better way so that I can change only one place? I read about command/macro but not sure how to use it in this case.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image13}
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image14}
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image18}
\item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image19}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...[one *ring* to rule them all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring)!

Comment: @Werner: you ninja'd me with this association...

Comment: That's one of LaTeX's selling points. I don't think automatically scaling images is very easy in Word, for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest defining the scale factor as a macro `\imagescale` (say). This way, a single change will affect everything:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\newcommand{\imagescale}{0.2}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \includegraphics[scale=\imagescale,valign=t]{example-image}
  \item \includegraphics[scale=\imagescale,valign=t]{example-image}
  \item \includegraphics[scale=\imagescale,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that [`scale` (like `angle`) can't be set globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164116/5764).