# adjustbox and includegraphics page selection

Tags: graphics, size, adjustbox, page

I want to use the `adjustbox` package to include graphics in `beamer` presentations. I prefer it over `graphicx` because it has `max size` option which only scales the figure when its size is larger than a certain size.

But I've found a problem when I need to select a page from a multipage figure (usually made with `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`).  While using `\includegraphics`, it's possible to use `page=x` (defined in `pdftex.def`) option to select which page to be included but this option is not available in `adjustbox`. Therefore the best command I could do to include certain page from a multipage pdf file with fixed maximum size in beamer is:

```
\newcommand{\mygraphic}[2][]{%
     \par\centering
     \adjustbox{max size={\textwidth}{.9\textheight}}%
        {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}\par}
```

where `#1` is an optional parameter used to fix page selection when needed and `#2` is the mandatory filename.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to avoid using `includegraphics` inside `adjustbox` if I want to use `page=x` option?
2. Is it possible to fix `max size` with a general `adjustboxset` command? (I think it isn't with `export` class option but I'm not sure)

Comment: Ignasi, @UlrikeFischer: `adjustbox` v1.1 2018/04/08 now passes the `page` key (and others) correctly. For images use `\adjustimage{key=value,...}{imagefilename}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\centering % just to avoid overfull box
\includegraphics[page=2,max size={\textwidth}{0.9\textheight}]{l3fp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Once you know the solution it's easier to find it in documentation, I've read `export` class option several times but with your example I've finally understood it.

Answer (score 1):

The `adjustbox` v1.1 from 2018/04/08 now correctly supports the `page` key. Instead of using the `export` option you can just use the macro `\adjustimage{<options>}{<filename>}`. Instead of using `\centering` just use the `center` key at the end.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}[2018/04/08]

\newcommand{\mygraphic}[2][]{%
     \par\noindent
     \adjustimage{#1,max size={\textwidth}{.9\textheight},center}{#2}%
     \par
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After bouncing back between this and [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31012), I decided I wanted to *both* set global keys for `adjustbox` (part 2 of your question) *and* sometimes also use `page=…` (part 1).<sup>1</sup> So I did this—note the use of **capitalized** `Export`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

% Load graphicx first and save its original \includegraphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\orig@includegraphics\includegraphics

% Using the capitalized 'Export' option replaces \includegraphics with
% \adjincludegraphics
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}

% Set some global adjustbox keys
\adjustboxset{trim=0.5in 0in}

% Define a new three-argument command:
%   \includegraphicspage{adjbox args}{graphicx args}{filename}
\newcommand{\includegraphicspage}[3][]{%
  \adjustbox{#1}{\orig@includegraphics[#2]{#3}\par}}
\makeatother
```

This allows me to do all of the following and have my `\adjustboxset` options apply in every case:

```
\begin{document}

% This is actually \adjincludegraphics; 'page' won't work
\includegraphics{singlepage.pdf}

% Pass an argument for graphicx
\includegraphicspage{page=3}{multipage.pdf}

% Also pass arguments for adjustbox
\includegraphicspage[width=\textwidth]{page=3}{multipage.pdf}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Why? Mainly because I already had a long document with many `\includegraphics`. It was easier to modify the few appearances of multi-page images.